# access req in expressjs 3 views

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to access my query params in my views in ExpressJS 3?

I have a url: http://example.com?search=blah

And in my view I would like to access the search param

I can pass it as a locals but wondering if I can access it directly - my experiments were not successful.

Not looking for the pros and cons of direct access - just want to know if it's possible and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ways to access `req.query` from your view:

#### Set it as a local in the call to `render`

```
function(req, res) {
  res.render('myview', {query: req.query});
};
```

in your view you can access `search` as `query.search`.

#### Set `res.locals`

```
function(req, res) {
  res.locals.query = req.query;
  res.render('myview');
};
```

in your view you can access `search` as `query.search`.

#### Use middleware

This is similar to the previous example but we can use middleware in a reusable way.

```
function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.query = req.query;
  next();
};
```

Any route that uses the above middleware, will have `res.locals.query` set.

---

#### edit

It appears that I misunderstood the question. The intent was to see if the request data could be accessed without use of the above techniques. As far as I know, it can not. Hopefully the above will still be useful for some readers.

Comment: I think he knows this. He wants to access it 'directly'. "I can pass it as a locals but wondering if I can access it directly "

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about "directly" at the end of the question. I'm hoping my answer could still be useful to people searching for the _title_ of the question. It looks like I just received my first downvote ever on SO. This makes me a sad panda.

Comment: It appears that what I want may not be possible - if no answers turn up I'll mark yours as valid since that is the best one can achieve and it's a fine answer Panda.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll add a note to the answer explaining the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure only locals get passed to the view.

> Not looking for the pros and cons of direct access - just want to know if it's possible and how.

There are no pros and cons. It's like saying I want to multiply 15 with 0 but I don't want the answer to be apple.

Answer (score 1):

middleware:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.param = req.param;
  next();
};
```

view:

```
<%= param.search %>
```