# Access req and res inside of app.locals

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

Trying to write some helper methods for an express 3.0 app. Here is an example to greet the user:

```
  app.locals.greet = function(req,res) {
    return "hey there " + req.user.name;
  }
```

However, `req` and `res` aren't available inside that function. How would I go about writing helpers that I can use inside my jade templates? Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by `writing helpers that I can use inside my jade templates`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my config `app.js` file! that should work to you as the variables will e available at that context.

```
app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(connect.compress());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public", { maxAge: 6000000 }));
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + "/public/img/favicon.ico", { maxAge: 6000000 }));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 15)),
    store: new MongoStore({ url: config.database.connectionString })
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~{   REQUEST   }~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~".cyan);
    res.locals.config = config;
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    res.locals.utils = viewUtils;
        res.locals.greet = function(){
                //req and res are available here!
                return "hey there " + req.user.name;
        };
    next();
});
app.use(app.router);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three parts of a simple example to show how a helper function could use `req.locals`:

#### helper function:

```
app.locals.greet = function(user) {
  return "hey there " + user.name;
}
```

#### view template:

```
h1= greet(user)
```

#### render function:

```
function(req, res) {
  res.render('myview', {user: req.user});
};
```

If you need more information on setting `req.locals`, see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571069/access-req-in-expressjs-3-views/13571615#13571615) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331776/accessing-express-js-req-or-session-from-jade-template/13572244#13572244).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a middleware function/handler that will set those values using the `req`/`res` objects before the router calls it's render method. As well, this handler needs to be defined after the information you need to know has been defined. (ie. after session middleware)

```
// AFTER sessions/auth/etc -- app.use(express.session(...))
app.use(function (req, res) {
    // set any locals using req/res
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    res.locals.greet = function () {
        return "hey there " + req.user.name;
    }
});
// BEFORE router -- app.use(express.router);
```

See the API documentation on [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) for further information.