# Node.js: use underscore along with ejs to render html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, underscore.js, ejs

I'm currently using EJS templating engine to render my HTML pages, but I want to add underscore to simplify the pre-processing. Right now I do this and it works:

```
var _ = require("underscore");

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var data = {};
    data.people = [{ name: "john" }, { name: "marry" }];
    data._ = _; // inject underscore.js
    res.render('index', data);
});
```

Now to render the HTML I have access to underscore:

```
<% _.each(people, function(person){ %>
    <div><%= person.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

However, I have to inject underscore for every route, is there a way to **always** inject underscore? (maybe somewhere in app.engine setting ?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could bind `_` to `app.locals`.

> Once set, the value of **app.locals** properties persist throughout
>   the life of the application, in contrast with res.locals properties
>   that are valid only for the lifetime of the request.

```
app.locals._ = _;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var data = {};
    data.people = [{ name: 'john' }, { name: 'marry' }];
    res.render('index', data);
});
```

In your view:

```
<% _.each(people, function(person){ %>
    <div><%= person.name %></div>
<% }); %>
```

There is a great answer from another SO user: [Access req and res inside of app.locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886897/access-req-and-res-inside-of-app-locals)

See [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html) on `app.locals` vs. `req.locals`

I just added quotes around the names 'john' and 'marry'